# Uniform convergence of integral

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to understand this for the first time.
I have to check whether $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x}sin(x)dx$ is uniformly convergente or not.
My guess is it is not convergent if $\alpha \in ]0,\infty[$ but I'm not 100% sure if I proved it right, or how to prove it.
So what I have done is:

Let's assume it is uniformly convergent.
Then there is a $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \alpha \in]0,\infty[$
$$\left\lvert \int_{p}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x}sin(x)dx \right\lvert < something$$ not sure what number to put in "something" for a contradiction.

And if this is true then the function
$$f(\alpha)= \int_{p}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha x}sin(x)dx \hspace{0.1cm} , \alpha \in ]0,\infty[$$ is bounded.
I know that $\lim_{\alpha \to 0} f(\alpha)$ doesn't exist. Is this a contradiction? Why does this contradict the fact that $f$ is bounded? (if $\lim_{\alpha \to 0} f(\alpha) = \infty$ I wouldn't have any doubts, but it doesn't - the limit just doesn't exist so I don't know how to justify).

I hope I was clear about my doubt.
Thank you!

Comment: It follows because $f(\alpha)$ is monotone. Hence $\lim_{\alpha\to 0} f(\alpha)$ either exists in $\mathbb{R}$ or the function diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that $\int_p^\infty e^{-\alpha x} \sin x \, dx$ does tend to $0$ as $p \to \infty$ and is bounded for fixed $\alpha$ since the integral is convergent.  It is not uniformly bounded and does not tend uniformly to $0$ -- which you have not shown.

Comment: Showing that the uniform Cauchy condition is violated is usually the most expedient way to prove non-uniform convergence particularly when the integrand oscillates through $0$ as it does here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral is uniformly convergent for $\alpha \in [a,\infty)$ where $a > 0$ by the Weierstrass M-test, but not on $(0,\infty)$.

For the first integral, with $\alpha_n = (2n\pi + \pi)^{-1} \in (0,\infty)$ we have

$$\left|\int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi} e^{-\alpha_nx_n} \sin x \, dx\right|\geqslant  e^{-(2n\pi+\pi) \alpha_n}\int_{2n\pi}^{2n\pi+\pi} \sin x \, dx = 2 e^{-(2n\pi+\pi)\alpha_n}= 2e^{-1}$$

Since the RHS does not converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence is violated.

Comment: Thank you so much, may I ask for the formulation of the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence? (I've never heard of it) Thank you!

Comment: $\int_a^\infty f(x,\alpha) \, dx$ is uniformly convergent for $\alpha \in D$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $C$ such that $\left|\int_{c_1}^{c_2}f(x, \alpha) \, dx \right| < \epsilon$ when $c_2 > c_1 > C$ for ALL $\alpha \in D$.  Above I showed there is an $\epsilon_0$ for which this can't hold because for any $C$ I can pick $2n\pi > C$ and an $\alpha = \alpha_n$ such that the absolute value of that integral is greater or equal to $\epsilon_0$,

Comment: Its really another consequence of $\int_p^\infty f(x,\alpha) \, dx \to 0$ uniformly as $p \to \infty$.

Comment: Understood perfectly! Thank you ;)

Comment: @PedroFernandes: You're welcome.  Now that you know this technique it may come in handy for future problems.

Comment: Yes, it probably will!!!

Comment: Hmm I was reviewing this and I didn't understand one thing, probably because I don't know basic theory once again. So I understand that $x < 2n\pi +\pi \implies e^{-x} > e^{-(2n\pi + \pi)}$ but why does that inequality hold, why can we take the exponent out and the absolute value? (I mean the inequality in your answer).

Comment: OK I got it ahah forget it.

Comment: All we need to do is produce for every $C$ some $c_2 > c_1 >C$ and some $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$ such that $\left| \int_{c_1}^{c_2} e^{-\alpha x} \sin x \, dx \right| \geqslant \epsilon_0$.  I chose $c_1 = 2n\pi$ and $c_2 = 2n\pi +\pi$ because $\sin x$ is nonnegative on $[2n\pi, 2n\pi + \pi]$ and we can eliminate the absolute value and take that term outside of the integral while preserving the inequality.

Comment: Yeah when I did it I saw why, but you did it so fast that I thought I didn't need to do any calculation :P thanks!